# chrome extension : max width for the devtools subpanel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing Dev tools extension to the  elements subpanel ( see the'Redder' plugin in attached image)

[image]

I am using following code to add the subpanel to the elements panel

```js
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane("Redder",
    function(sidebar) {
         sidebar.setPage("panel.html");
         
    }
);
```

Now my question is, is there a way to set maximum width to this panel so that user's won't be able to shrink it to all the way right.

this is just a sample plugin, I need this for my actual plugin.

Comment: DevTools apparently ignores `min-width` of a panel.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't anything in the Chrome's [DevTools Panels API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels) to restrict resizing.